# .Net MVC Multi tenant URL Single sign on (SSO)

Tags: .net-core, single-sign-on, multi-tenant

I have an application in .NET Core and my multi tenant implementation as follows:

> Tenants are identified through URL( [www.example.com/**tenant1*](http://www.example.com/**tenant1*)* or
> [www.example.com/**tenant2**](http://www.example.com/**tenant2**)).The tenants use shared database, i.e.,
> the data is separated using id for each tenant in each tables and
> each query then usage tenantId to fetch database corresponding to
> each tenant.

I need to implement SSO in the application and I am not able to find any solution for **URL based multi-tenancy implementation for SSO**.

So if a user changes tenantName in the URL, and if the user is a valid user for the tenant, he will be allowed, else not.

I am using cookie middleware for authentication/authorization for now:
https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/security/authentication/cookie.html

Comment: check out this project. You need to dig in. They are also having multi-tenancy https://github.com/joeaudette/cloudscribe

Answer (score 1):

You can accomplish this via the existing owin middlewares. just extract the url segment in the middleware and find

1. Is the current request authenticated
2. If authenticated, is the currently logged in user having permission to view the data of this tenant
3. if (1) & (2) are valid, pass the request through the other middlewares
4. else, return unauthorized.

All this takes is a custom middleware that you can add to the owin pipeline to handle all of this magic.